# Watch NSString length in debugger

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I have an NSString variable called `myText`.
How to watch `[myText length]` in xcode debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the debugger console to evaluate a property of an object in Xcode, the debugger output view actually functions as an input, too.

[image: Example output]

Obviously first you have to Hit a breakpoint ...

It actually works with GDB and LLDB and you have to type in the output console :

```
print (int)[myText length]
```

Comment: print [detailText length]                                                       
Unable to call function "objc_msgSend" at 0x307abfac: no return type information available.
To call this function anyway, you can cast the return type explicitly (e.g. 'print (float) fabs (3.0)')

Comment: Ok, i just noticed that i works only with gdb, not with lldb change the debugger editing the current scheme and  and then type : print (int)[text length]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @aleroot's solution, you can use the variable view of the debugger as well.
You can right click on the view and select "Add Expression" and type in whatever you want to monitor. It is a little cumbersome compared to @aleroot's solution, but the merit of this method is that it automatically shows again when you hit the same breakpoint next time.

[image]

Comment: Add the cast to int ... (int)[detailText length]